# Problematic "suggest"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> It is the calculus, rather than the consent, in James
>   Buchanan and Gordon Tullock’s "Calculus of Consent" that suggests
>   the decision rules they propose should be adopted.
>
> Moral Foundations of Politics by Ian Shapiro

I want to understand this sentence and i have two versions. The problematic word is "suggest".

> (1) In James Buchanan and Gordon Tullock’s "Calculus of Consent",
>   calculus, rather than the consent suggests the decision rules which
>   they propose that these rules should be adopted.
>
> (2) In James Buchanan and Gordon Tullock’s "Calculus of Consent",
>   calculus, rather than the consent suggests that the decision rules
>   which these man propose should be adopted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of your suggested sentences is quite grammatical, so I will discuss the original sentence.

It is the word "calculus", of the two words in the title, that **suggests** the decision rules.
[American Heritage Dictionary "suggest"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=suggest)
3. To make evident indirectly; intimate or imply

The authors propose that these decision rules should be adopted. The reviewer of the book is expressing their opinion about where the rules came from; specifically, that the rules are implied more by calculation (calculus) than by agreement (consent).